# How to write a dynamodb query in swift to fetch all values with a particular partition key

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I am unable to find a way to write a dynamodb query in swift to fetch results that have a particular partition key.

For example say my partition key is "bigCompany" and sort key is "email". Now I want to fetch all emails with their "bigCompany" name as "xyz".

For reference my code structure is very similar to the load function below. But this one uses `.load` to fetch one value instead of querying. Basically I need to find a way to call `dynamoDBOBjectMapper .query()` given the constraints I mentioned above. Any help would be much much appreciated!

```
func getTableRow() {
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    //tableRow?.UserId --> (tableRow?.UserId)!
    dynamoDBObjectMapper .load(DDBTableRow.self, hashKey: (tableRow?.UserId)!, rangeKey: tableRow?.GameTitle) .continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error == nil) {
            if (task.result != nil) {
                let tableRow = task.result as! DDBTableRow
                self.hashKeyTextField.text = tableRow.UserId
                self.rangeKeyTextField.text = tableRow.GameTitle
                self.attribute1TextField.text = tableRow.TopScore?.stringValue
                self.attribute2TextField.text = tableRow.Wins?.stringValue
                self.attribute3TextField.text = tableRow.Losses?.stringValue
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to get item from table.", message: task.error!.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            })
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. They key is using keyConditionExpression correctly. Below is my answer.

```
            let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()

            queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#bigCompany = :bigCompany"
            queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = ["#bigCompany": "bigCompany",]
            queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":bigCompany" : self.bigCompany,]

            dynamoDBObjectMapper.query(Requests.self, expression: queryExpression) .continue(with: AWSExecutor.immediate(), with: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
                //If added successfully
                if((task.result) != nil) {
                    let results = task.result! as AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput
                    print(results.items)
                } 
                else {
                    //do error checking here
                }
            })
```